# Angular AppConfig loaded from server, but needed in module setup

Tags: angular, ng-modules, angular-providers

A lot of examples on the web around getting the configuration at `APP_INITIALIZER` in angular (now 8), here is one that sums it up: https://davembush.github.io/where-to-store-angular-configurations/

NgModule looks finally like this

```
@NgModule({
 // ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // My modules here
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfigHere)
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: load,
      deps: [
        HttpClient,
        ConfigService
      ],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
 // ...
})
```

I am stuck because I have modules that are initliazed with configuration, one of which is the infamous `AngularFireModule` like this

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfigHere)
```

I tried so many tricks, cannot seem to get the hang of it, how do we pass configrations that are loaded from sever, to modules set up in the imports?

**Note** the imports fire before the APP_INITIALIZER

Answer (score 0):

1: provide fire module without calling initializeApp;
2: provide factory for `FirebaseOptionsToken` token with `ConfigService` dependency
3: provide anything you would pass to initializeApp as a second param for `FirebaseNameOrConfigToken`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,AngularFireModule],
  providers: [
   {/* your APP_INITIALIZER here */}
   { provide: FirebaseNameOrConfigToken, useValue: null},
   { 
    provide: FirebaseOptionsToken,
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => configService.pathToFirebaseConfig},
    deps: [ConfigService]
  ]
})
```

this will make factory to be called lazily. Note, that you cannot inject anything related to firebase module to ConfigService or other initializer dependencies, because factory I proposed will be called earlier than config arrives.

Comment: I tried that, the APP_INITIALIZER still runs later than the factory for the token, and it is already a promise that sets up the config, so by the time it loads the config, the factory has already tried to retrieve `pathToFirebaseConfig`. Did you ever implement this?